# convergence of $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p(\log{x})^q}\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

I would like to find such $p$ and $q$ for which is this integral convergent:
$$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p(\log{x})^q}\, dx$$
I showed so far that for $p>1$ it's convergent (and of course there is no problem in point $2$). So I would like to know what happens when $p\leq 1$. 
(I would like to get some hint instead of the whole solution)

Comment: Separate into $p = 1$ and $p < 1$. You need different arguments for those cases.

Comment: When $\text{p}=1$: $$\int_2^\infty\frac{1}{x\ln^\text{n}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\ln^{1-\text{n}}\left(2\right)}{\text{n}-1}$$ When $\Re\left(\text{n}\right)>1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For sufficiently large $x$, we have $$\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x^p (\log x)^q} $$so you can compare, this works for $p < 1$, you'll need to deal with $p=1$ separately (in fact, this becomes an easy integral).